# Jquery set input value with like condition

Tags: php, jquery

Simple question I need to set value to the input text with datalist option :

```
<input type="text" class="floating-input" name="id_app" id="id_app" list="apps" placeholder=" " title="Choose one" autocomplete="off" value="">
<datalist id="apps">
  <?php foreach ($applications as $value): ?>
    <option value="<?= $value->id_app . ' - ' . $value->name_app?>"> <!-- will produce ex: [APP-0001 - Hello world] -->
  <?php endforeach ?>
</datalist>
```

In the database I just input the `APP-0001` for `id_app` field refference. The problem when I want to edit it using api request, it will produce `APP-0001` and I can't set the value for `$('#id_app')` input because the value attribut has different "string value" to what api serve.

```
<!-- input value="APP-0001 - Hello world" -->
<!-- what_api_give="APP-0001" -->
```

I can just change what backend give to front via api, but it will affect other moduls in the system that using the same api request, it needs extra effort to do that.
Can JQuery pick the value that has "value" with LIKE operator, for example in MySQL query id_app LIKE "APP-0001%" so I can set the `$('#id_app')` with `.val('APP-0001%')`.

Thank you

Comment: have you checked why are you getting that extra zero

Comment: @MohammadFahadRao Sorry it's just typo

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors

Comment: Thank you for answering, I have the solution but it slightly different how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

`value~="APP-0001"` may work.

```
let cek = $('#apps').find('option[value~="APP-0001"]').val();
$('#id_app').val(cek);
```